# requests.get() and / or BeautifulSoup() behaviour inconsistent

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I have the following code:

```
__PARENT_TAG = "article"

def _navigate_to_xxx(self):
    """acquire html from xxx and beautify the raw html"""
    html = requests.get(xxx.__BASE_URL + xxx.__EXTENDED_URL)
    self.beautified_html = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")

def _extract(self):
    """helper function that extracts elements from beautified_html and returns it"""
    element_list = None
    element_list = self.beautified_html.findAll(self.__PARENT_TAG)
    logging.debug("The number of __PARENT_TAG is: {0}".format(len(element_list)))
    return element_list
```

The problem is for the same web page, the result I got from the debugging line is sometimes 18 and sometimes 20 (I expected 20).

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I think we would need to see what your __PARENT_TAG call looks like to exactly diagnose it, but I do know that BeautifulSoup made from regular websites' html has a lot of empty and extraneous bits in it. Look closer at the exact behavior of findall() in the bs4 docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all and make sure that you're in the right part of your html tree. Some parts might have an extra `<div>` class or something you didn't expect.

Comment: I added it to my original question